# Reverse engineer a matrix multiplication

Tags: matrices, convex-optimization

Here's a puzzle. I'm looking for ideas on how to research solutions.

Given:

- Secret $n\times 1$ vector $x$
- Public $m\times n$ matrix $B$ with $m \ll n$
- (assume $B$ has rank $m$)
- Public product $b = B \cdot x$

In general, $x$ cannot be determined from $b$ and $B$ since $x$ has more elements than $B$ has rank.

Now, assume it is known that $x$ has at most $k$ non-zero elements, where $k \ll m$, but it is not known which elements are nonzero.  For instance, if $k=1$, then $b$ is a scalar multiple of one column of $B$.

How would I go about determining $x$?  Do any standard optimization techniques come to mind?

Comment: I am closing as too broad; the keyword you want to search for for information on this problem is "compressed sensing."

Comment: OK, thanks for that- I will look into it.

Comment: multiply by $B^{\top}$ to get $B^{\top}Bx=B^{\top}b$ to get a square system, quasi solved by $x\approx (B^{\top}B)^{-1}B^{\top}b$

Comment: @janmarqz But $B^T B$ is not invertible.

Comment: well, if it were

Comment: @janmarqqz That is a good idea (maybe trying to use pseudoinverse) but if you try it, you'll find it doesn't work very well.  The $x$ you get is usually not sparse.  That's why people use convex optimization to solve this kind of compressed sensing problem.

Comment: @littleO, thanks for the advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical way to estimate $x$ would be to minimize $\| x \|_1$ subject to the constraint that $Bx = b$.  This optimization problem is known as the "[basis pursuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_pursuit)" problem.

(We would prefer to minimize the number of nonzero components of $x$ subject to the constraint that $Bx = b$, but that is a nonconvex problem.  Penalizing the $\ell_1$ norm of $x$ does a good job of promoting sparsity, and gives us a convex problem for which very efficient algorithms are available.)

Comment: When you say "penalizing $\ell_1$," you just mean making $\ell_1$ norm the objective variable?

Comment: @BrandonKuczenski Yes, making the $\ell_1$ norm the objective function, that's all I meant.